# How to get cinematic look filter with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to get video look like this cinematic look footage from normal footage.
Understanding to use video filters, I don't hit what is the best filters.

This is original:

[image]

What I want to get:

[image]

Could you show your opinion?

thanks.

Comment: Often called a "bloom" effect.

Comment: HI llogan, Thanks comment and information! I'll try to build that.